# Qt5 connection causes Unhandled Exception or HEAP CORRUPTION

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, qt5

I'm using Qt5.5 on VS2010SP1. I have a QCheckBox in a dock widget which controls whether a QTableView (promted to ConsoleWindowView) in the same dock widget is auto-scrolled or not.

**Problem 1:**

When I connect the QCheckBox::stateChanged signal to the QTableView's slot (autoScroll) all seems well unless I change the state of the QCheckBox and exit. At exit I get the error:

> Debug Error! Program: QtTests.exe HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after
>   Normal block (#4613) at 0x02B63850. CRT detected that the application
>   wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.

If I exit without activating the QCheckBox, the exit is normal.

**Problem 2:**

Thinking this might be related to destruction order, I tried to "remember" the connection and disconnect in the QTableView destructor but when I try to assign the return value from QObject::connect to a QMetaObject::Connection member variable I get:

> Unhandled exception at 0x669859c2 in QtTests.exe: 0xC0000005: Access
>   violation writing location 0xabababc7

Code is below, followed by the associated ui file.

The area which crashes is in Gui.h, method connectControls. For Problem 1, the configuration is:

```
QObject::connect(AutoScrollCheckBox, &QCheckBox::stateChanged, this, &ConsoleWindowView::autoScroll); // CRASH1: Debug Error! Program: QtTests.exe HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#4613) at 0x02B63850. CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.
//QMetaObject::Connection NewConnection = QObject::connect(AutoScrollCheckBox, &QCheckBox::stateChanged, this, &ConsoleWindowView::autoScroll);
//AutoScrollConnection = NewConnection; // CRASH2: Unhandled exception at 0x669859c2 in QtTests.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xabababc7
```

For Problem 2, the configuration is:

```
//QObject::connect(AutoScrollCheckBox, &QCheckBox::stateChanged, this, &ConsoleWindowView::autoScroll); // CRASH1: Debug Error! Program: QtTests.exe HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#4613) at 0x02B63850. CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.
QMetaObject::Connection NewConnection = QObject::connect(AutoScrollCheckBox, &QCheckBox::stateChanged, this, &ConsoleWindowView::autoScroll);
AutoScrollConnection = NewConnection; // CRASH2: Unhandled exception at 0x669859c2 in QtTests.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xabababc7
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>

#include "Gui.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Gui w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

**Gui.h**

```
#ifndef QTTESTS_H
#define QTTESTS_H

#include <iostream>

#include <QTimer>
#include <QHeaderView>
#include <QCheckBox>
#include <QObject>

#include "ui_Gui.h"

class ConsoleWindowModelClass : public QAbstractTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ConsoleWindowModelClass(QObject *parent)
        : QAbstractTableModel(parent)
        , RowCount(0)
    {
        //
        ControllerTimer = new QTimer(this);
        connect(ControllerTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(updateController()));
        ControllerTimer->start(2000);
    }
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
    {
        return RowCount;
    }
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
    {
        return 2;
    }
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
    {
        if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
        {
            return QString("Row%1, Column%2")
                .arg(index.row() + 1)
                .arg(index.column() +1);
        }
        return QVariant();
    }
    QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
    {
        if (orientation == Qt::Horizontal)
        {
            if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
            {
                switch(section)
                {
                case 0:
                    return "Stamp";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    return "Text";
                    break;
                default:
                    return QString("Column %1").arg(section + 1);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (orientation == Qt::Vertical)
        {
            if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
            {
                return QString("%1").arg(section + 1);
            }
        }
        return QVariant();
    }
protected:
    unsigned int RowCount;
    QTimer *ControllerTimer;
    private slots:
        // GUI triggered
        // Timer triggered
        void updateController()
        {
            beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), RowCount, RowCount);
            RowCount++;
            endInsertRows();
        }
};

class ConsoleWindowView : public QTableView
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    ConsoleWindowView(QWidget *parent = 0)
        : QTableView(parent)
        , AutoScroll(true)
    {
    }
    virtual ~ConsoleWindowView()
    {
        //disconnect(AutoScrollConnection);
    }
    void setTheModel(QAbstractItemModel *TheModel)
    {
        QTableView::setModel(TheModel);
        connect(model(), &QAbstractItemModel::rowsInserted, this, &ConsoleWindowView::modelRowsInserted);
    }
    void connectControls(QCheckBox *AutoScrollCheckBox, QCheckBox *ReverseList, QPushButton *MarkerA, QPushButton *MarkerB, QPushButton *MarkerC, QPushButton *MarkerD)
    {
        try
        {
            //QObject::connect(AutoScrollCheckBox, &QCheckBox::stateChanged, this, &ConsoleWindowView::autoScroll); // CRASH1: Debug Error! Program: QtTests.exe HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#4613) at 0x02B63850. CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.
            QMetaObject::Connection NewConnection = QObject::connect(AutoScrollCheckBox, &QCheckBox::stateChanged, this, &ConsoleWindowView::autoScroll);
            AutoScrollConnection = NewConnection; // CRASH2: Unhandled exception at 0x669859c2 in QtTests.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xabababc7
        }
        catch (const std::exception &Exception)
        {
            std::cerr << "ConsoleWindowView::connectControls: " << Exception.what() << std::endl;
        }
    }

    public slots:
        void modelRowsInserted(const QModelIndex & parent, int start, int end)
        {
            if (model() != nullptr)
            {
                if (AutoScroll)
                {
                    scrollTo(model()->index(start, 0));
                }
            }
        }
        void autoScroll(int State)
        {
            if (State == 0)
            {
                AutoScroll = false;
            }
            else
            {
                AutoScroll = true;
            }
        }

signals:

protected:
    bool AutoScroll;
    QMetaObject::Connection AutoScrollConnection;
private:
};

class Gui : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Gui(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Gui();

protected:
    ConsoleWindowModelClass *ConsoleWindowModel;

private:
    Ui::Gui ui;
    void createConsoleWindow();

    //
private slots:
    // GUI triggered

};

#endif // QTTESTS_H
```

**Gui.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#include <QTimer>
#include <QHeaderView>
#include <QCheckBox>
#include <QObject>

// Qt model handling the BusSimLowRateTx message from BusSim to DataSwitch.

#include <QAbstractTableModel>

#include "Gui.h"

Gui::Gui(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    // create UI
    ui.setupUi(this);
    //
    ui.actionExit->setShortcuts(QKeySequence::Quit);
    ui.actionExit->setStatusTip(tr("Exit the application"));
    connect(ui.actionExit, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(close()));
    // create models
    ConsoleWindowModel = new ConsoleWindowModelClass(this); // should be deleted as part of QMainWindow destructor, by specifying this as the parent.
    //
    // connect ConsoleWindowModel to the View(s)
    createConsoleWindow();
}

Gui::~Gui()
{
    // ConsoleWindowModel - should be deleted as part of QMainWindow destructor.
    //ConsoleWindowView *View = static_cast<ConsoleWindowView *>(ui.ConsoleOutputTable);
    //disconnect(ui.AutoScroll, &QCheckBox::stateChanged, View, &ConsoleWindowView::autoScroll);
}

void Gui::createConsoleWindow()
{
    ConsoleWindowView *View = static_cast<ConsoleWindowView *>(ui.ConsoleOutputTable);
    View->setTheModel(ConsoleWindowModel);
    for (int c = 1; c < View->horizontalHeader()->count(); ++c)
    {
        View->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(c, QHeaderView::Stretch);
    }
    // connect the other ConsoleWindow Controls to the model
    View->connectControls(ui.AutoScroll, ui.NewestAtTop, ui.MarkerA, ui.MarkerB, ui.MarkerC, ui.MarkerD);
}
```

**Gui.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Gui</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="Gui">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>593</width>
    <height>652</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Gui Tests</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <property name="sizePolicy">
    <sizepolicy hsizetype="Maximum" vsizetype="Preferred">
     <horstretch>0</horstretch>
     <verstretch>0</verstretch>
    </sizepolicy>
   </property>
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_7"/>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>593</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuFile">
    <property name="title">
     <string>File</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="actionExit"/>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuView">
    <property name="title">
     <string>View</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <addaction name="menuFile"/>
   <addaction name="menuView"/>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
  <widget class="QDockWidget" name="ConsoleOutput">
   <property name="windowTitle">
    <string>Console Output</string>
   </property>
   <attribute name="dockWidgetArea">
    <number>8</number>
   </attribute>
   <widget class="QWidget" name="ConsoleOutputDock">
    <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_4">
     <item row="0" column="0">
      <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
       <item row="0" column="0">
        <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
         <item>
          <widget class="QCheckBox" name="AutoScroll">
           <property name="text">
            <string>Auto Scroll</string>
           </property>
           <property name="checked">
            <bool>true</bool>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QCheckBox" name="NewestAtTop">
           <property name="text">
            <string>Newest At Top</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QPushButton" name="MarkerA">
           <property name="styleSheet">
            <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);</string>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string>Marker A</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QPushButton" name="MarkerB">
           <property name="styleSheet">
            <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);</string>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string>Marker B</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QPushButton" name="MarkerC">
           <property name="styleSheet">
            <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);</string>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string>Marker C</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QPushButton" name="MarkerD">
           <property name="styleSheet">
            <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);</string>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string>Marker D</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </item>
       <item row="1" column="0">
        <widget class="QTableView" name="ConsoleOutputTable"/>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <action name="actionExit">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Exit</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionECIO_Outputs">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Enlightenment Monitor</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionECIO_Inputs">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Enlightenment Control</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionSHM_Control">
   <property name="text">
    <string>SHM Input</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionSHM_Output">
   <property name="text">
    <string>SHM Output</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <zorder>ConsoleOutput</zorder>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: `QObject` is a properly designed C++ class that is always safe to destruct. **In no case** are you required to manually disconnect connections simply because you happen to be destructing the objects involved. Your code has other problems, but adding such "workarounds" is not going to help any.

Comment: I suspected as such having never had this before. I think the relationship between the controls and the QTableView is wrong but I can't see how to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are statically casting an instance of `QTableView` to `ConsoleWindowView`. It's not going to work, since it's not a `ConsoleWindowView`. What did you expect? Why did you `static_cast` it?

If you're unsure if a static cast will work, use `qobject_cast`. It'd have failed, yielding a nullptr result, and you'd know that you must stop and figure out why you're not getting the right class instance. And you aren't because your UI file is broken - you must have the instance of the right type in the UI file.

Fix your UI file to instantiate the correct class:

1. Right-click on the ConsoleOutputTable in the design view.
2. Click on *Promote to...*.
3. Enter `ConsoleWindowView` in *Promoted class name:*.
4. Enter `gui.h` in the *Header file:*.
5. Click *Add*.
6. Click *Promote*.

In any case, you don't need to manually track object connections.

Other points/rants:

1. If you want a timer instance, just put a `QTimer` member there - what's the point of using a pointer and prematurely pessimizing via indirect reference and an extra heap allocation? Make your life easy.
2. The abstract item view already has a property named `autoScroll`. You're making everyone's life horrible by messing with an identical name for a new property. Name it something else, like `scrollToNewest`.
3. Your auto-scrolling table view should have a property that controls its behavior. You can then connect that property to controls at a place where it's useful to know about source controls like checkboxes. Tightly binding the view to some random controls is a bad idea. The view should be general. The form where you use it has knowledge of other controls, and knows how to bind the view to such controls.
4. `setModel` is a virtual method. Override it, don't create your own.
5. You will confuse yourself silly by having variable names starting with a capital letter. Don't do that. Classes start with capital letters, variables and members start with lower case.
6. The use of `signals` and `slots` section macros should only be used when the signals and/or slots are logically related and there's many of them - so many, that the use of `Q_SIGNAL` or `Q_SLOT` prefixes would be a bit much. In most cases, you have a handful of signals/slots and you should use the prefixes instead. You can then easily group the signal and slot declarations with other related methods, so that the grouping of declarations follows function, not implementation details.
7. In Qt 5 you don't need the `Q_SLOT` prefix at all, any method can be a slot with the new `connect`syntax. You only need the `Q_SLOT` or `Q_INVOKABLE` prefix if you wish the method's metadata to be available at runtime.

Taking the above into account, this is how the `ConsoleWindowView` class should look:

```
class ConsoleWindowView : public QTableView
{
   Q_OBJECT
   Q_PROPERTY(bool scrollToNewest READ scrollToNewest WRITE setScrollToNewest)
   bool m_scrollToNewest;
   void modelRowsInserted(const QModelIndex &, int start, int end) {
      Q_UNUSED(end)
      if (model() && m_scrollToNewest) scrollTo(model()->index(start, 0));
   }
public:
   ConsoleWindowView(QWidget *parent = 0) : QTableView(parent), m_scrollToNewest(true)
   {}
   void setModel(QAbstractItemModel *TheModel) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
   {
      QTableView::setModel(TheModel);
      connect(model(), &QAbstractItemModel::rowsInserted, this, &ConsoleWindowView::modelRowsInserted);
   }
   Q_SLOT void setScrollToNewest(bool s) { m_scrollToNewest = s; }
   bool scrollToNewest() const { return m_scrollToNewest; }
};
```

The `Gui` class, after decoupling the console view from the concrete controls used to tweak it:

```
class Gui : public QMainWindow
{
   Q_OBJECT
   Ui::Gui ui;
   ConsoleWindowModel consoleWindowModel;
   void connectConsoleWindow() {
      auto view = ui.ConsoleOutputTable;
      view->setModel(&consoleWindowModel);
      for (int c = 1; c < view->horizontalHeader()->count(); ++c)
         view->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(c, QHeaderView::Stretch);

      connect(ui.AutoScroll, &QCheckBox::toggled, view, &ConsoleWindowView::setScrollToNewest);
   }

public:
   Gui(QWidget *parent = 0) : QMainWindow(parent) {
      ui.setupUi(this);
      ui.actionExit->setShortcuts(QKeySequence::Quit);
      ui.actionExit->setStatusTip(tr("Exit the application"));
      connect(ui.actionExit, &QAction::triggered, this, &QWidget::close);
      connectConsoleWindow();
   }
};
```

Note that we simply *name* the `connectConsoleWindow` method according to what it does. You have named it **wrongly** as `createConsoleWindow` and then **commented** on its behavior - namely, that it doesn't create anything, but only connects stuff. **This is a horrible antipattern and must be considered to be an instant code review failure**. Name things according to what they do, when feasible (it is here). Make the code self-documenting.

Finally, this is how you should instantiate long-lived members such as timers, etc - without the use of raw pointers and explicit memory allocation that is subject to human mistakes:

```
class ConsoleWindowModel : public QAbstractTableModel
{
   Q_OBJECT
   unsigned int m_rowCount;
   QTimer m_controllerTimer;
   void updateController()
   {
      beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), m_rowCount, m_rowCount);
      m_rowCount++;
      endInsertRows();
   }
public:
   ConsoleWindowModel(QObject *parent = 0)
      : QAbstractTableModel(parent)
      , m_rowCount(0) {
      connect(&m_controllerTimer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &ConsoleWindowModel::updateController);
      m_controllerTimer.start(2000);
   }
   [...]
```

Comment: Many thanks for such an excellent answer and for taking the time to pass on the best practice I was hoping for.

Comment: Let me disagree with your point about 'Q_SLOT vs slots': prefixing even a single slot doesn't improve readability a bit, it only adds visual clutter, to say nothing about excessive UPPERCASES_WITH_UNDERSCORES...

Comment: @vines It's a moot point, with Qt 5 you don't need to declare slots as such unless you want them accessible by name at runtime. I've updated the answer accordingly.